# Joomla current path

Tags: php, joomla

I have Joomla Component `administrator/components/com_mycomp`

And I have `import.php` file in this folder.

How I can access import.php from com_mycomp.php.

```
require_once('./import.php');
```

Gives error file not found. Because current path is `/administrator` , instead of `administrator/components/com_mycomp`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use PHP's `__DIR__` constant, that always points to the current file's directory.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/import.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

use JPATH_BASE;

```
<?php
    require_once(JPATH_BASE.'/directory/subdirectory/import.php'); 
 ?>
```

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_find_your_absolute_path

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Joomla constants, use

**JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR** - The path to the administrator folder.

or

**JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR** - The path to the administration folder of the current component being executed.

for more refer-
https://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Let me know if still face any issue.